# Python Ctypes memory allocation for c function

Tags: python, memory-management, ctypes

I currently have a python callback function that calls a c function using ctypes library. The c function requires a pointer to a structure for example animal_info_s. I instantiate the structure and pass it as a pointer to the c function and it works. The issue I'm having is when I have multiple threads calling the callback, I'm finding the information being passed back is mixed up between the threads.

```
class animal_info_s(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [('dog_type',          ctypes.c_uint16),
                ('cat_type',          ctypes.c_uint16),
                ('bird_type',         ctypes.c_uint16),
                ('epoch_time',        ctypes.c_uint16),
                ('more_information',  ctypes.c_uint16)]


_mod = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary('bbuintflib.dll')
animal_info_s = animal_info_s()
get_animal_data = _mod.get_animal_data
get_animal_data.argtypes = [ctypes.POINTER(animal_info_s)]
get_animal_data.restype =   ctypes.c_int

# Python Callback
def GetAnimalData():
    animal_info_p = animal_info_s
    res = get_animal_data(animal_info_p)
    if (res != 0):
        print("Failed to get animal info")
        return

    print ("Receive Time - %d\nDog: %d\nCat: %d\nBird:%d" %(animal_info_p.epoch_time,
                                                            animal_info_p.dog_type,
                                                            animal_info_p.cat_type,
                                                            animal_info_p.bird_type))
```

I think what is happening is when I instantiate the structure, it is using the same memory location every time. How do I create a new memory location for each thread calling the callback?

Comment: I'm not a ctypes expert, but are you using `animal_info_p = animal_info_s` in `GetAnimalData` for each thread?  That would be using the same struct instance everywhere (and would explain the strange behavior).  Don't you want `animal_info_p = animal_info_s()` instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following line should be removed.  It redefines the name `animal_info_s`  as a `class animal_info_s` instance, which then hides the class.

```
animal_info_s = animal_info_s()
```

The following line should be changed from:

```
animal_info_p = animal_info_s
```

to:

```
animal_info_p = animal_info_s()
```

The original line made another name for the `animal_info_s` name from the first error, which was the one-and-only instance used in the threads.  the recommended line creates a new instance of the `animal_info_s` class each time the callback is called.

Comment: When creating an new instance of animal_info_s, do I have to free any memory used or does it get handled by Python? Python normally handles it but I'm worried this is a special case (This object is for C) and it might create a memory leak somewhere.

Comment: It is freed by Python when the instance goes out of scope at the end of the function.  If a C function kept a reference to the memory, you would have to keep a reference to the object in Python as long as the C function needs it.